# Is there are way to limit max rows in multi-textbox in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if there was a way to limit the text lines/rows in a Multiline-TextBoxt to like 200 as in .Net?  I was trying to set the amount of rows that would be allowed in the box.

$userTextBox.Lines.Length = ?

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there isn't a built-in way then you can try and limit it yourself with an event handler that ignores key presses if the current pressed key is the Enter key (13):

```
$textbox_KeyDown={

    if($_.KeyValue -eq 13 -and $textbox.Lines.Count -ge 200) 
    {
       $_.SuppressKeyPress=$true
    }
}
```